# How to use hierarchical Dirichlet process to predict new word's probability

Tags: topic-models

Assuming that I have already obtained document's topic distribution and topic-word distribution, how to predict the probability of one document will contain some word w_n?

Answer (score -1):

When we predict the probability of one document,We can use the generated topic-word distribution as a fixed distribution during the iteration, only updating the document-topic distribution,we can get the docuemnt-topic on the test dataset until the convergence.